How to store github settings as code instead of in a UI
Is there a way to store my github repo's settings "as-code" rather than interacting with the settings via UI?  Aka these things:

I would like to do this so that:

We can keep a history of changes
Changes can be PR reviewed

Right now our team has several admins and people frequently update settings.  This makes it hard to understand why settings are setup a certain way.  This is paticularly an issue with branch protection rules:

I would like some way to store all of these settings in a text file, either in YAML or Terraform or something else.  Is this possible?

It would be nice if you could put a file in .github/, but I don't believe there's anything like that. Many settings can be queried and set with the Github API. You could write those as a configuration file, plus a program to apply changes via the API.

An Infrastructure as Code tool such as OpenTofu (a fork of Terraform) with a GitHub provider should let you keep your configuration outside of GitHub and have it sync stats to the definition you've written instead: https://search.opentofu.org/provider/opentofu/github/latest - see the documentation for the types of resources you can configure.
